# Visual Studio Resource Generation - Custom Tool Namespace

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a C# class library that contains several resources files organized in folders. Since I want the generated classes to be all in the same namespace I'm setting the CustomToolNamespace property of each resource file.

However I discovered through Reflector that although the classes are all being generated in the same namespace the path to the embedded resources contains the directory name in which the resource file is placed.

For example in a project where *FolderCustomNamespaceRes.resx* is placed inside a directory named *Folder*.

*removed dead ImageShack link*

And where CustomToolNamespace for *FolderCustomNamespaceRes.resx* is set to PublicResourcesTest, Reflector shows that the path to the embedded resource assembly is PublicResourcesTest.**Folder**.FolderCustomNamespaceRes.resources

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some search I found out that the manifest name of the embedded resource can be controlled by adding metadata in the `.cspproj` file.

Before you would have something like:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Folder\FolderCustomNamespaceRes.resx">
   <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
   <LastGenOutput>FolderCustomNamespaceRes.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
   <CustomToolNamespace>PublicResourcesTest</CustomToolNamespace>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

And to control the manifest name you would have to add:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Folder\FolderCustomNamespaceRes.resx">
   ....
   <LogicalName>$(RootNamespace).FolderCustomNamespaceRes.resources</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done automatically by the IDE so it's not a bug, but unfortunately the only way it appears you can suppress this behaviour is by using ReSharper as outlined [here](http://blog.colinmcclure.com/2009/06/15/visual-studio-2008-resharper-and-folder-namespace/).

Comment: That ReSharper option is not applicable to the case in hand. Resource generation is controlled by a custom tool provided by Visual Studio.