# renaming resource files correctly for satellite assemblies

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just created a Visual Studio 2010 console application project, c#.
Then I added a folder named *de*.
Then I added a resx file called *myres.resx* to the main folder.
Then I translated the resx to german and copied this to the *de* folder and renamed the file to *myres.de.resx*

Visual studio created the satellite assembly almost correctly. What is wrong is the name of the resource in the satellite assembly. It is *Projectname.de.myres.de.resources* instead of *Projectname.myres.de.resources*. How can I remove the superfluous *de*?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For automatically generated code in your project you have a very little power to change the namespace and this usually follows the folder structure of your project.

You can, however, edit your files manually to change the namespace. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043399/visual-studio-resource-generation-custom-tool-namespace).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot, that helped.
I edited Projectname.csproj file:

```
 <ItemGroup>
   <EmbeddedResource Include="de\MyResource.de.resx">    
     <LogicalName>ResApp.MyResource.de.resources</LogicalName>  
   </EmbeddedResource>
   <EmbeddedResource Include="MyResource.resx">
     <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
     <LastGenOutput>MyResource.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
     <SubType>Designer</SubType>
   </EmbeddedResource>
 </ItemGroup>
```