# Resource View blank?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2012 C# project which was copied from another visual studio project and renamed. The project compiles fine and works. I tried to  use the Resource View to edit the icon and the window is completely empty. 
Any ideas?
thank you!

Comment: Just to check the obvious, are you sure that you copied the project file (.csproj), together with all of the associated source (.cs), resource (.resx) and image (.ico/.png) files?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is caused by renaming the project as it changes the [namespace used for resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043399/visual-studio-resource-generation-custom-tool-namespace) as well. Did you rename the project within the Visual Studio or just renamed the file names?